# What Is the Most Efficient Way to Infer Dates When Reading a CSV Into Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, io

**Objective**: to read in a csv file into a Pandas dataframe and not have to manually call at date columns

Here is the code I am using currently,which provides a dtype of 'O' on my date column:

```
df = pd.read_csv(r"D:\time_stamp_ex.csv",
                parse_dates=False, 
                infer_datetime_format=True,
                date_parser=pd.to_datetime)
df
```

This isn't super helpful since you don't have the file, so here is a dataframe snippet that produces exactly what I have in my csv file:

```
d = {'time_stamp': ['9/22/2017','9/15/2018','8/7/2017'],
     'category': ['A1','A2','B1'],
     'number':[12345678,12345678,12345678]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df
```

Reading the [Pandas documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) I don't see that I have missed anything, but I am open to this being a simple answer.

Answer (score 1):

Pandas will only attempt to `infer_datetime_format` for what you specify in `parse_dates`. You currently have this set to `False`. You need to tell it which columns in your csv file contain dates.

I'm not sure if this answers your question as I'm unsure what 'not have to manually call at date columns' means. Do you mean you don't want to have to convert the date columns separately from reading in the file or that you don't want to tell `read_csv` which columns contain dates?

Comment: Ideally, I don't want to have to tell read_csv which columns contain dates and I would want it to determine based on data patterns in the column that a column should be one of these types: np.dtype('datetime64[ns]') == np.dtype('<M8[ns]')

Comment: Perhaps tell it to attempt to parse all the columns as dates. It will only convert a column if every single value in the column can be parsed as a date.